# Why is itertools izip faster than equivalent function from documentation?

Tags: python, python-itertools, built-in

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) is written:

```
def izip(*iterables):
    # izip('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax By
    iterators = map(iter, iterables)
    while iterators:
        yield tuple(map(next, iterators))
```

But when i run test with `itertools.izip` it works faster, then when I run `izip` function from my module. Why is this happening? Can I run the module function as fast?

Timer test:

```
>>> t = Timer("dict(izip_2(keys,values))", "from __main__ import keys, values, izip_2")
>>> t2 = Timer("dict(itertools.izip(keys,values))", "from __main__ import keys, values")
>>> 
>>> print min(t.repeat(5, 10000))
31.6810410023
>>> print min(t2.repeat(5, 10000))
2.50448894501
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my CPython, `itertools` is coded in C rather than Python:

```
In [1]: import itertools

In [2]: itertools.__file__
Out[2]: '.../lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/itertools.so'
```

Generally, precompiled C tends to be faster than interpreted Python, so this could well be one reason.